# React Native Linking to open Facebook Messenger

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, facebook-messenger

How can I open Facebook Messenger by linking? 
I have a userid. I want to chat with users. But some userid is scope app id that I can't connect to them. 
Is there any way to open Messenger with every returned id type?

Answer (score 1):

You can use m.me links to open messenger:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/referral-params

Comment: M.me link will open a conversation with your app in messenger, which opts them in. Once they either tap a get started button on your welcome screen or send you a message you'll get a webhook event that includes their page scoped I'd, which you can use to send them a message.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are like me and still searching then just add this :

Linking.openURL(`http://m.me/<PAGE_NAME>`)

**Instead of:**

Linking.openURL(`fb-messenger://<PAGE_NAME>`)

Linking.openURL(`'https://www.messenger.com/t/<PAGE_NAME>`)

Linking.openURL(`fb-messenger://user//<PAGE_NAME>`)

Here is [Official Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links)