# How to send a message in FB Messenger thru React Native Linking

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am attempting to send a **message** through FB messenger from my React Native project.

I have the following code that opens the messenger app, but does not start to compose a new message with the message body filled. I am attempting to have the same type of user experience one would have if they were clicking a link to open an email and compose a message with the body filled.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
const openMailClient = () => {
    return Linking.openURL(
      `mailto:?subject=Terms and Conditions&body=${rawHtml}`
    );
  };
```

The above is what I intend to do for a FB Messenger Message, I am just not certain what the syntax is.

This is what my FB Messenger Linking looks like:

```
const openFbMessengerClient = () => {
    const fbNo = "";
    return Linking.openURL(`fb-messenger://`);
  };
```

Do you know how I can change my openFbMessengerClient function to operate like the email function posted above? I would like to open a new message with the recipient unfilled, and with the message body filled with a string of my choice.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!,

I've tried this code, and it does work to open the FB Messenger app, but it does not start a new conversation with the body filled with a string of my choice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Linking to open Facebook Messenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46192806/react-native-linking-to-open-facebook-messenger)

Comment: No, that link shows how to navigate to a linked facebook page. I'm not trying to do that. I am trying to link to a new message, so a user can send my string to a facebook friend in messenger